# Will the Javascript performance improvements from Trace Trees find their way into other interpreted languages?

Tags: javascript, performance, compiler-construction, interpreter

It sounds like Mozilla is having good luck improving JavaScript performance with [TraceMonkey](http://weblogs.mozillazine.org/roadmap/archives/2008/08/tracemonkey_javascript_lightsp.html). See also Andreas Gal's [paper on Trace Trees](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~franz/Site/pubs-pdf/ICS-TR-06-16.pdf).

Are these improvements available to other interpreters/compilers and if so, does this mean we'll see a cascade of improvements in other interpreted languages?

Comment: I'd like to know too, can't really find any references to the use of trace trees in other languages ... the only think I can think of is to look his main paper up on citeseer to see anyone is citing it in research on other languages ;)

Comment: Well, other than ActionScript, of course

Comment: Jaykul: the research is new, so its unlikely to show up in many other places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a research JVM by Andreas Gal called [HotPath](http://HotPath.Org/), and some people from his team are currently working on adding nested trace tree based JITting to [Maxine](http://Research.Sun.Com/projects/maxine/) (Sun's new research JVM written in Java) and HotSpot. So, at least it is showing up in other VMs for other languages as well.

Also, the new [PyPy](http://PyPy.Org/) JIT compiler (currently being prototyped in Prolog) uses some kind of tracing technique, although I don't know how closely related that is to Gal/Franz style nested trace trees.

The [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) guys are definitely aware of this work, and very open to experimentation. I wouldn't be surprised, if some advanced compilation techniques start showing up there, soon.

BTW: there is a Ruby VM written in JavaScript, called [HotRuby](http://HotRuby.Accelart.Jp/). If you run that on TraceMonkey, you get trace tree based Ruby for free :-)

Comment: I hope that "BTW" is a joke :)

Answer (score 0):

The only possible answer to this is: **Hopefully!**