# Will Ruby ever be *fast*?

Tags: ruby, performance

Will Ruby ever see a performance boost as Javascript has seen recently? Can a new VM make it really, *really*, fast? Or do we have to assume all the benefits of Ruby have an inescapable performance penalty?

What methods could be taken to improve its performance compared to other faster languages?

Comment: Subjective and Arugmentative, not to mention I see the members of the Ruby community grabbing pitchforks and torches. I wish you luck, sir.

Comment: Wow, how is this "blatantly offensive"?

Comment: Technically there's no reason why it shouldn't profit from the same kind of VM optimizations that JavaScript, Java and .NET get.

Comment: Ruby is Open Source. If you want it to be faster you can start learning how it works under the hood, cozy up to the development community, learn the mores and traditions for proposing changes in that group and start *helping* make it faster.

Comment: "I think everyone can safely assume it is somewhat slower than other scripting languages" - how can we safely assume that??

Comment: May be Ruby is not as fast .. but ruby programs can be made faster -
http://www.hxa.name/articles/content/ruby-speed-guide_hxa7241_2007.html

Comment: I'm quite sure that the "benefits" of Ruby do _not_ require it to be slower than other languages, as for instance Common Lisp, which has quite any language feature one could currently blame for bad performance, has quite a few well performing implementation.  It's just a matter of priorities, and as others have pointed out, some people are working on the performance part.

Comment: I don't think this is argumentative; it's an important question to any Ruby developer or any developer who is considering learning Ruby. It's up to the commenters to keep the conversation civil.

Comment: @dmckee That's such a cop-out. A project is open-source so that it can benefit from the goodwill of contributors, not so that the core devs have an excuse any time someone has a valid suggestion or issue.

Comment: @Lucas Oman: Asking here if Ruby might, someday be super duper fast is not in fact a valid suggestion to the project. It's vapor. And off topic vapor at that, because it doesn't have an actual answer except "Wait and see."

Comment: Fortune-tellers on SO are notoriously unreliable. However, the infallible Magic 8-Ball sez: "Outlook Not So Good"!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988/jorg-w-mittag) pointed me in the direction of [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) when I [asked about Trace Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140241/will-the-javascript-performance-improvements-from-trace-trees-find-their-way-into) finding their way to other scripting languages. Check them out for a faster Ruby.

As an interesting aside, [unladen-swallow](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/wiki/ProjectPlan) is trying to speed up Python by using [LLVM](http://llvm.org/).

Interesting stuff. There are plenty of unexplored tricks to speed up scripting but I wonder if language developers consider it a priority versus language features and libraries.

Comment: MacRuby is also creating an LLVM-based virtual machine for Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

> I think everyone can safely assume it is somewhat slower than other scripting languages

Ruby 1.9 should actually be about the speed of CPython.

Comment: Please specify which Python implementation you're talking about. CPython, Jython and IronPython have rather different performance characteristics and all three of those are "Python".

Comment: I was talking about the C version of python2 (don't know anything about the performance of python3) and the C version of ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 4):

[Maglev](http://maglev.gemstone.com/) is a ruby implementation that is based upon an existing Smalltalk engine that's been targeting the upper reaches of scaling and usage.

It's designed to be "significantly faster" than existing ruby implementations, you can watch a talk by one of the [Maglev Architects](http://pivotallabs.com/talks/28-maglev) if you're interested.

In the same way that different Javascript implementations run faster or slower on different browsers, it's worth noting that ruby itself runs [nearly twice as fast](http://antoniocangiano.com/2009/08/10/how-much-faster-is-ruby-on-linux/) on Linux vs Windows.

Answer (score 2):

JRuby has a jrubyc compiler that can create jvm .class files from ruby files. I have never used it, only took a quick look at it, so I don't know how much of Ruby is supported for bytecode compiling. If it is compiled down to bytecode, then the jvm ought to optimize just like any other bytecode.

Comment: One of the most advantages here will be the memory management. Don't know about YARV, but MRI is very bad in that.

Comment: Sadly jRuby is, for some reason, quite a bit slower than Ruby.

Comment: @DigitalRoss I had heard that jruby, using jruby not the script bindings, was muh fastr than ruby 1.8. As stated, I have never used either jruby or cruby for real projects. Mostlyjust for code golf.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 :: JRuby 1.7 -- http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=yarv&lang2=jruby

Answer (score 1):

Well there's definitely a lot of room for improvement. Here's a list of benchmark times for an   N-body simulation (a math-heavy algorithm): http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=nbody&lang=all

Ruby 1.9 takes 34 minutes whereas one of the faster web-server-friendly language (C#) takes just 37 seconds.  So **C# is over 50X faster** for this particular task. It could be argued that this isn't the type of task that Ruby would be used for anyway. But still there's the question of scalability.

For Ruby to become MUCH faster it really needs to be compiled in some way.  This can be in a just-in-time fashion like the V8 Javascript engine.  Or it can be done more like ASP.NET which maintains 'cached' compilations behind the scenes.  In other words, .NET has the ability to compile on the fly, but in so doing you'll notice that it takes its sweet time.  But the payoff is that it doesn't need to re-compile until the code changes and as the benchmark above suggests -- the final compiled code is very fast.  So I'd think Ruby (or a variant of it) would be better off copying .NET's technique in this respect.

Comment: I'd consider Scala to be web-server-friendly as well, as it runs on the JVM, and it's faster than C# (24.26). Java itself is also faster than C#. Still, that's an interesting benchmark.

Comment: (and note that C# is "only" run on Mono here and not on the Microsoft CLR, which I assume is a bit faster than Mono).

Comment: Joachim, thanks for catching that.  I reworded my answer a bit.  I still make the reference to C# because that's what I'm more familiar with.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer -- see http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/demo/benchmark.php?test=nbody

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ruby will get significantly faster.

The new Javascript VMs prove that it is possible for an dynamic, weak-typed language which makes significant changes to the execution paths at runtime to be compiled effectively.  The LLVM provides a platform-agnostic foundation on which this might happen.  These innovations will eventually trickle into all scripting languages.

[MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/), [Maglev](http://maglev.gemstone.com/), or [Rubinius](http://rubini.us/) might be first to market with this kind of speed, but the C implementation will probably get there as well.

JRuby, it should be noted, is [obsessed with speed](http://blog.headius.com/2009/04/how-jruby-makes-ruby-fast.html) and has several "Ruby-like" [prototype](http://blog.headius.com/2008/03/duby-type-inferred-ruby-like-jvm.html) [languages](http://blog.headius.com/2009/08/introducing-surinx.html) which allow developers to trade certain features for improved performance.

Honestly, the main thing holding Ruby back is that for many, many purposes, it is already fast enough.  If you'd like to solve an [n-body problem](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32q/benchmark.php?test=nbody&lang=all), you should probably look elsewhere.  But if you'd like to build a smooth, maintainable web-based application, Ruby will get you into production faster and with great maintainability.  And your VCs will be so impressed, they will give you enough money to scale. At which time, you can rewrite your choke points as inline C or Java.

Comment: Ruby has acquired a reputation for not scLing well. With Twitter going to scala, ruby may not be the way to get vc captial.

Comment: Twitter has hit the point where Ruby is no longer the best choice for all its functions.  Nothing scales like C and Java, but these languages are very slow to build in.  For many websites that aren't going to be featured on the Oprah Winfrey program and CNN, Ruby offers a good mix of rapid development and performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ruby can get faster -- at least to the point where it is no longer an issue.

It will no longer be an issue when it is as fast as any other comparable language. And even then, only if it is equally fast on comparable features.

Why? If it is slower than anything comparable, then there is a way to do it faster, so it is possible. And with the momentum Ruby has, it probably WILL get faster.

Answer (score 0):

#### Ruby is getting faster

While jRuby often gets clobbered in simple benchmarks, with optional optimizations turned on it starts to look good.

And the official Ruby interpreter is now YARV, although most people haven't experienced it yet because they are still on 1.8.